# How Can Create A Class List In Python

Tags: python, list

I'm learning C++ now, so I usually compare the C++ with Python. I found the list in C++ is so different from Python. For example, when I define a "struct", then create a list of them, I would use this code:

```
    struct foo exm[3]
```

It'll create a list which contain 3 elements of foo, also I can initialize the element if I want. I can use exm[i] to index the list, and it's the only way I can use the element, these elements are anonymous I think.

How can I do the same progress in Python? I think I should create a new "class" to define the same "struct" in C++. But how about the list? The problem is I must create the explicit element and append it to the list later. How can I create that list quickly? On the other hand, how can I create a list that contains some new "class" object that is anonymous?

Maybe it's a stupid question and without any practice, I'm just curious about it. Many thanks.

Comment: In Python a list is a container that does not care about its contents. You can "initialize" your list with list comprehension: [exm() for _ in xrange(3)]

Comment: You don't declare lists with expected type values the way you do in C/C++/Java/other languages. Python doesn't care about types in that way. In fact, Python lists are heterogenous and may contain many types. `[1, 'apple', {'pear': True}, False]` is a valid list in Python.

Comment: I'm also going to recommend against what @Schore said (sorry) because pre-initializing a list in Python is, IMO, very bad practice. You should create the list and then call `append` or `extend` as needed.

Comment: I also would not do it but thats what he asked for.

Comment: Very suitable for this to be the chapter about List Comprehensions: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Initializing lists is not as bad a practice as @Schore; and @Two-Bit Alchemist" make it sound. I.e. it's better to initialize list in cases they're class attributes and define the class's default behaviour, than instantiate class attributes when program state changes. Initializing lists can prevent monkeypatching and excessive use of `hasattr` checks for anyone wanting to extend your code's functionality as well. Since python lists are overallocated arrays instantiating a larger list at program start can give a smoother feel to the execution (avoids copying) if you're writing an app. Win/Lose

Answer (score 0):

You can create list and give elements in  the constructor, like this:

```
In [4]: l = [1, 2, 3]
In [5]: l, type(l)
Out[5]: ([1, 2, 3], list)
In [6]: class A: pass
In [7]: foo = A
In [8]: l = [A(), foo()]
In [9]: l
Out[9]: [<__main__.A instance at 0x7fe56ebb1cf8>,  <__main__.A instance at 0x7fe56ebb1ef0>]
```

Comment: Why did you introduce a `foo` variable?

Comment: In this not necessary, but it shows that any class can be assigned in variable and use like same this class.